# JavaScript local storage not saving or retrieving information

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm making a simple math game where with Math.random() are generated two number and random sign, plus or minus. The user should provide an answer in an input box. The problem that i face is when i try save score and high Score in the local storage and then retrieve it on the next page reload. There are no error just the variables are undefined. For other strange reason the `highScore` is undefined always. How to make the `localStorage` save `score` and `highScore` right, and retrieve with on the next page reload without `undefined`, correctly ?

```
<div class='window' id='gamesDIV'>
        <h1 id='scoreEnd'>Score</h1>
        <h1 id='highScore'>HightScore</h1>
        </center>
        <div class='button' onClick='prepareGame()' id='specialRed'>Start</div>
        <div id='gameWindow'>
            <div style='white-space: nowrap;'>
                <p id='expression'>5-3</p>
            </div>
            <div id='score'>0</div>
            <div id='time'>5</div>
            <input onchange='CheckResult()' onkeyup='CheckResult()' id='answer' placeholder='Answer' type='number'></input>
            <center>



        </div>
    </div>
```

```
var DP = 10;
    var topUp = 2;
    var result;
    var score = window.localStorage[score];
    var game = false;
    var Gsec = 5;
    var lastExp = null;
    var TimerFnc;
    var highScore = window.localStorage[highScore];
    var scoreEndValue = window.localStorage[score];
    $('div#percentage').hide();
    $('div#SR').hide();
    $('div#gamesDIV').hide();
    $('div#gameWindow').hide();
    document.getElementById('scoreEnd').innerHTML = window.localStorage[score];
    document.getElementById('highScore').innerHTML = window.localStorage[highScore];

    function prepareGame() {
        document.getElementById('answer').value = null;
        score = 0;
        $('div#specialRed').hide();
        $('div#menu').hide();
        $('div#gameWindow').show();

        $("div#gamesDIV").css("margin-left", "0");
        $("div#gamesDIV").css("width", "100vw");

        $("div#gamesDIV").css("background-color", "black");
        Start();
        TimerFnc = setInterval(Timer, 1000);
        game = true;
        Gsec = 5;
    }

    function Timer() {
        if (Gsec > 0) {
            Gsec--;
            console.log("Remaining seconds", Gsec);
            // document.getElementById('time').innerHTML="5";
            document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = Gsec;

        } else {
            game = false;
            EndGame();
        }
    }

    var num1, num2;

    function Start() {
        game = true;
        console.log('Starting generating numbers.');
        num1 = Math.round(Math.random() * topUp);
        num2 = Math.round(Math.random() * topUp);
        var sign = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);
        console.log(num1, num2, sign);
        if (sign == 1) {
            sign = '+';
            result = num1 + num2;
        } else {
            sign = '-';
            if (num1 <= num2) {
                num1 = Math.round(Math.random() * topUp);
                num2 = Math.round(Math.random() * (num1));
                result = num1 - num2;
            } else {
                result = num1 - num2;
            }
        }
        console.log(num1, num2, sign);
        if (lastExp == (num1 + sign + num2)) {
            Start();
        } else {
            document.getElementById('expression').innerHTML = num1 + sign + num2;
            lastExp = num1 + sign + num2;
        }
    }

    function EndGame() {
        clearInterval(TimerFnc);
        if (score > highScore) {
            highScore = score;
        }
        document.getElementById('highScore').innerHTML = "Highscore: " + highScore;
        document.getElementById('scoreEnd').innerHTML = "Score: " + score;

        $('div#specialRed').show();
        $('div#menu').show();
        $('div#gameWindow').hide();

        $("div#gamesDIV").css("margin-left", "5vw");
        $("div#gamesDIV").css("width", "95vw");

        $("div#gamesDIV").css("background-color", "white");
        console.log(score, highScore);

        window.localStorage['highScore'] = highScore;

        window.localStorage['score'] = score;

        console.log(score, highScore);


    }

    function CheckResult() {
        if (result == document.getElementById('answer').value) {
            Gsec = 5;
            //  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML="5";
            document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = Gsec;
            console.log('True');
            topUp = Math.round(topUp * 1.4);
            document.getElementById('answer').value = null;
            Start();
            score = score + 1;
            document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = score;
        } else {
            console.log('false');
        }
    }
```

[This is before starting the game and all of the above functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSBtk.png)

[This is after game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz6lK.png)

[This after the page reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmVXd.png)

Comment: After applying the change specified by hossein, Also make sure that the browser in question supports the localStorage object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must change your code like this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#Example

```
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');

var cat = localStorage.getItem('myCat');
```

Comment: It works. The problem was that i had written localStorage.getItem(highScore) instead of localStorage.getItem('highScore'). Thanks a lot!